Matplotlib Makes Trippy Incorrect plots
I fill a numpy array with 0 or 1 depending if a computed array indexed value is more or less than a given value.  This results in an array of zeros and ones.  Matplotlib doesnt think so
The comparison is computed d=sin(b*pi/180)*x+sin(a*pi/180)*cos(b*pi*180)*y
The unique statement prints " unique values in space [0. 1.]"
Last image shows same code with True/False array instead of 0/1
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
tan=np.tan
sin=np.sin
cos=np.cos
pi=np.pi
x=4
y=3
Max=.3

sizeOfSpace=2000
alpha=np.linspace(-10, 10,sizeOfSpace)
beta=np.linspace(-10, 10,sizeOfSpace)

space=np.zeros((sizeOfSpace,sizeOfSpace))
for i,a in enumerate(alpha):
    for j,b in enumerate(beta):
        d=sin(b*pi/180)*x+sin(a*pi/180)*cos(b*pi*180)*y
        space[i,j]=int(0) if d<Max else int(1)
plt.imshow(space,cmap=plt.cm.gray)
plt.colorbar()
print(f'unique valeus in space {np.unique(space)}')




Any suggestions how to make the binary image?

Make sizeOfSpace=200, not 2000.

I cannot reproduce the shown image.  Perhaps you have the default interpolation set somewhere.  What does plt.rcParams["image.interpolation"] give you?  For me, it gives 'antialiased'.

The following snippet does the job:
import itertools
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def generate(N=2000, threshold=.3, x=4, y=3):
    
    alpha = np.linspace(-10, 10, N)
    beta = np.linspace(-10, 10, N)
    A, B = np.meshgrid(alpha, beta)

    D = np.sin(B * np.pi / 180.) * x + np.sin(A * np.pi / 180.) * np.cos(B * np.pi * 180.) * y
    S = D > threshold
    
    return S

S = generate(N=2000)

fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.imshow(S, cmap=plt.cm.gray)


The gray area are not in between values but spatial aliasing. You can confirm it by analyzing dtype and modalities:
S.dtype       # dtype('bool')
np.unique(S)  # array([False,  True])

Changing the resolution will give you different patterns:
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3)
for axe, N in zip(itertools.chain(*axes), [100, 200, 300, 500, 1000, 2000]):
    S = generate(N=N)
    axe.imshow(S, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    axe.set_title("N = %d" % N)



"The gray area are not in between values but aliasing" +1

Thanks. I’m looking to get the binary image. Any suggestions how to do that?

It is a binary image, but the resolution will give you different patterns.

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


array = np.random.rand(100, 100) > 0.5


plt.imshow(array, cmap='gray')
plt.show()


List item


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
